# How to send username password via bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Normally we can send message between two Android devices using a Bluetooth chat app.

I want to send a username and password instead of a normal message and at the same time the receiver should receive that.

All via Bluetooth

Comment: Welcom to S.O., @m-m-samy What framework/library are you using? A little more information and a code snippet would help people help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on what information would be appreciated.

Comment: sure sir, this is my first query in S.O.thats why

Comment: And how does it differ from sending any other string?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the data into a single string... like JSON, for example.

#### Send

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("username", uname);
data.put("passwd", pass);

// bluetooth.send(data.toString());
```

#### Recieve

```
// String msg = bluetooth.receive();

JSONObject data = new JSONObject(msg);
String uname = data.getString("username");
```

Comment: sorry for asking. i have code for bluetooth chat to  send normal string. i have to sent username and password.to do this what should i do. without json can i do this

Comment: What exactly is your issue? How is sending JSON any different than a "normal string"? Can you answer that?

Comment: In other words, you can just build the string "username: password", or a phrase "Your username is X and your password is Y'. It really does not matter as long as you parse it out properly in the receiver.

Comment: thanks for rply. i'll try